# maven not picking dependencies from my local repository

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a module (let's say A, version 1) that is available in my maven global repository. I have now modified the code inside this module and bumped the version up to version 2.
Now, the code for this module has not been committed and the global repository doesn't now about this new version. However, I have built the project and version 2 is available in my local .m2 folders.

I am now working on a new module (let's say B) that depends on module A, version 2. maven is not picking up this dependency on module A. And my code is not linking to classes in module A.

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I have performed a clean install of module A, and I can see the classes in the local repository.

Best,
Pulkit

Comment: Have you performed `install` of module A?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov - yes i have

Comment: Show us both your `pom.xmls`-s and an `ls -al ~/.m2/repository/com/foo/projectA/2.0-SNAPSHOT` of the installed artifact.

Comment: In the new module - ie Module B -is your version info for Module A correct(ie a 2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you are using an IDE, which I presume you do (you are using maven), you could try to update the project configuration and update the dependencies. Also make sure you refer to the correct versions of your modules in your pom.xml file(s) . This is all presuming you have performed a clean install of your 'A version 2', of course. Good luck!

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick answer. I have updated the versions in both modules A and B and performed a clean install. weirdly enough, when i do an mvn dependency:tree to inspect the dependencies, it shows that A hasn't been pulled in.

Comment: did you, once more, after updating the versions in B, update the project configuration and update dependencies? Do you experience any build path errors?

Comment: So I updated my version in A, updated the dependency in B, clean installed A, and then build B. B is unable to resolve any class in A. So it doesn't compile. If I remove the reference to the classes, it does.

Comment: If B uses A, you should commence with installing A. then, make sure B refers to the correct version of A in your pom.xml. Then, update dependencies of B. Open the pom.xml file of B with a meven POM editor, if you should have one. (Eclipse provides this.) Then go to dependency hierarchy, and check if the version of A really is 2.

Comment: If that does not work, there must be another problem. Try finding the following folder in the directory of your workspace:
...\workspaces\project-name\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\project-name-web\WEB-INF\lib and delete those .war- and .jar-files. Then once again perform a clean install. I must warn you that I looked up this directory quickly on my machine, and that this is only valid when using a web-project ;)

Comment: hi, thanks. option 2 worked. i had some dirty jar files left over that were causing the trouble. i thought i had deleted them, but i screwed up. thanks for your help @K Maertens